# Probability from 2 continuous random variables with joint density

Tags: probability

How do you calculate the probability from two continuous random variables (X and Y) with joint density?

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{i.}~&~\mathsf P(0 \leqslant X \leqslant 1/2, 1/2 \leqslant Y \leqslant 1)
\\[1ex]
\mathrm{ii.}~&~\mathsf P(0 \leqslant X \leqslant 1/4)
\\[2ex]
f(x,y)&=\begin{cases}2/3\,(2x+y) &\mbox{for}& 0 ⩽ x ⩽ 1, 0 ⩽ y ⩽ 1\\ 0 &&\mbox{elsewhere}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Comment: Just integrate the density over the regions of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes figures are worth 1000 words:

[image]

[image]